# Margin percentage error in safari

Tags: css, cross-browser, safari, margin, percentage

Everything works fine in Firefox and chrome when i give margin in percentage with absolute position

`margin:50% 0 0 60%;position:absolute;z-index:5;`.

FF/chrome calculating the percentage according to the screen size . but In safari it seems to be margin percentage are double.so i tried `calc()` with vw

`margin:calc(50vw * 0.54) 0 0 calc(50vw * 0.60);position:absolute;z-index:5;`

No effect in safari.I think i'm missing something .please help

Added [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xjSx3/3/) please see the difference between ff/chrome and safari

This is my second time , now i came up with the fiddle

Comment: If HTML change is possible, try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/quzmx/1/ (test1 and test2 are inside .content and .content has position relative set. works for my safari- on win7 though)

Comment: your idea works well in fiddle but not responding in my site pls see check and throw some solution http://192.185.56.215/~wwwtheam/demo/lookbook.html

Comment: what exactly should I look at? Which elements represent your test1 and test2?

Comment: the plus symbol with blue bg its not visible in safari .. only in few pictures

Comment: ah, I see know. but this isn't really corresponding with my JS fiddle. If I understand correctly, div.details should be inside div.item and .item should have position:relative.

Comment: Thanks for your effort.yes i tried that.if i change the div.details like that it is not clickable.so the animation are not working.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39724/discussion-between-sangeethk-and-vlad-saling)

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your problem `:)` maybe like this

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xjSx3/7/)

use `top: 50%` and `left: 50%` for test1 and test2

Comment: Thanks for the effort .. i tried top/left/right it works fine but  the overlay div is clickable and it has a jquery function onclick() ,if we use top/left.clicking option is not working.it clicks the div behind that(which also has a jquery function to do). hope you understand my problem.

Comment: can you add a jquery part in fiddle :)

Comment: it is working well in js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xjSx3/8/ . i'm ready to show my site please check this.http://192.185.56.215/~wwwtheam/demo/lookbook.html . throw me some solution please